# Eliminar registro repetidos en mysql

Tags: mysql

Consulta inner join msql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy batallando con una consulta, soy nuevo en sql.
Tengo esta base de datos y no logro recuperar `nombre_usuario` de la tabla `usuarios` por `id_chat`.

Mi consulta:

```
 select distinctrow  us.correo_usuario,me.sms,us.nombre_usuario from 
 detalle_usuario_chat as dtll inner join usuario as us
 on us.correo_usuario=dtll.correo_usuario
 inner join chat as ch
 on ch.id_chat=dtll.id_chat
 inner join mensaje as me
 on me.id_chat=ch.id_chat
 where dtll.id_chat='af8bbcc9-371d-4446-beb8-244a66831028';
```

Comment: Que error te arroja la consulta o cuál es el problema?

Comment: Me muestra mensaje repetido para cada usuario

Answer (score 0):

No te parece que sea un error en tu forma de entender el resultado de la query? Para cada chat puede haber mas de una instancia de `detalle_usuario_chat`? Por que si es asi, para los mensajes dentro del chat con id `af8bbcc9-371d-4446-beb8-244a66831028` va a aparecer cada mensaje una vez por cada row de `detalle_usuario_chat`.

No conozco msql, [por lo que no se si tu uso de `distinctrow` sea valido](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/predicados-all-distinct-distinctrow-o-top-24f2a47d-a803-4c7c-8e81-756fe298ce57).

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que tengas los datos mal registrados, porque la consulta no parece incorrecta. En cualquier caso, como únicamente parece que quieres obtener a los usuarios implicados en un chat, prueba así:

```
SELECT * FROM usuario
  WHERE correo_usuario IN (
    SELECT correo_usuario
      FROM detalle_usuario_chat
      WHERE id_chat='af8bbcc9-371d-4446-beb8-244a66831028'
  );
```

Para poder ayudarte más, edita tu pregunta añadiendo la estructura de tu base de datos en SQL con algunos datos de ejemplo con phpmyadmin, exportar. E indícanos qué resultado te gustaría obtener para esos datos de muestra.